# How to implement PUT method in Django

Tags: python, django

How can I enable the user to generate only one instance of an object “bet” with a POST method and modify it through a PUT method (for example)

**forms.py**

```
class BetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    team1_score = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=15)
    team2_score = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=15)
    match = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Match.objects.only('id'))

    class Meta:
        model = Bet
        fields = ('team1_score', 'team2_score', 'match')
```

**models.py**

```
class Bet(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    team1_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    team2_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.match))
```

**views.py**

```
    def post(self, request):  
        form = BetForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            team1_score = form.cleaned_data.get('team1_score')
            team2_score = form.cleaned_data.get('team2_score')
            match = form.cleaned_data.get('match')
            form = BetForm()
            return redirect ('home')
        args = {'form': form, 'team1_score': team1_score, 'team2_score': team2_score, 'match': match}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Comment: I assume you want to have the user create a single bet for each match, right? then he should be able to edit his bet using PUT method.

Answer (score 3):

> Enable the user to generate only one instance of an object “bet”...

For that, you want to add a user field to your `Bet` model. Here you will save a reference to the user making the request.

```
class Bet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='bets', blank=True)
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, related_name='bets')
    team1_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    team2_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'match')

    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.match))
```

Notice the `unique_together` option which makes sure a user can only create a single Bet instance for a given match.

> modify it through a PUT method (for example)

Django does not automatically parse the body for PUT requests like it does for POST. Browsers normally issue POST request on forms submission. If you still want to solve it using PUT, check this post (pun intended).

[Parsing Unsupported Requests (PUT, DELETE, etc.) in Django](https://thihara.github.io/Django-Req-Parsing/)

My suggestion is to modify your post view so it accepts an optional parameter `bet_id`. This you can define in urlpatterns. The view would then look like this one. You retrieve the bet if bet_id is provided and pass it to the form. This way it understands the user is modifying it.

```
def post(self, request, bet_id=None):
    if bet_id:
        bet = Bet.objects.get(pk=bet_id)
        form = BetForm(request.POST, instance=bet)
    else:
        form = BetForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        bet = form.save(commit=False)
        bet.user = request.user
        bet.save()

    # Do what you want here
```

Notice that we are not saving the form immediately (`commit=False`), so we could assign it to a user later on. This user is the logged in user from the `request` object.

Comment: Hint: I think `if pk:` should be `if bet_id:` in the view.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer was exactly what I needed, you truly helped me out a lot.

Comment: Thanks @Ralf, I corrected it.
@ nachomac welcome, you can accept the answer :)

Comment: Sorry @NourChawich, I've tried but I don't know how to define bet_id in urlpatterns. What I did was:
path('home/bets', views.BetView.as_view(), {'bet_id': Bet.objects.only('id').first().id}, name='bets'),

Comment: You need to specify it this way `path('home/bets/<int:bet_id>', views.BetView.as_view(), name='bets')` Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#example